# Handling active textbox in any application on computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, events

I'm writing a program that helps user when user is typing something on an application. A window will appear near where he/she is typing some text. I must learn a caret is blinking or when he/she types, this will be shown in a textbox or something like this that accepting input as text. Because some shortcuts must be eliminated, that not writes something on screen.

For example: 
when user is about to search something on google, I must know this, as webpage;
when user is trying to write some adress on browser, I must know this is an adress input,
or 
when user is trying to write some text on a winforms application, I must know this is a winforms application and user wants to input some text.

And:
when there is no input situation, for example user has not clicked any text area, and hits a keyboard button, I don't need this trigger my program.

How can I handle this situations, is it possible by C#?

Comment: This is possible, google for "C# keyboard hook". Come back for additional, more specific questions.

Comment: 1: a caret apperars on anywhere actively, 2: this caret belongs to one of them: a browser's text area, a web page, a windows application. Do you mean clear about step 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can; it just takes some extra thought. Like you can save some 'keywords' in the database to analyse patterns eg. for websites you can search for 'http' or 'www' or '.com', similarly for addresses you can search if any one has typed 'state or district or street number or pin code' etc; similarly for phone numbers you can check the country or district codes, but you'll have to restrict the user to some extent as there is lots and lots under the sun which user can search.

You can use web services to search the keywords from database at the same time when the user is writing in text area.

You can stop user from clicking buttons if nothing has been searches by putting various server side of client side validations which checks whether the desired text boxes are empty or filled with desired info...

hope this will help a little to your approach!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this seems raliable. But I need very instasnd and accurate result, a user types g and browser suggest user google, and 'g' and 'enter' I will lost the scenario.. If I can not find a more accurate answer, this was a good suggestion.

Comment: @LetheanHypnone threeFourSixOneThree meant that "user1343227" was being a bit harsh. For most native English speakers, telling someone to "put intelligence to it" is a suggestion that the person is acting stupid. I don't think that's what "user1343227" meant by it, but I'm going to just edit that so as not to cause any confusion. :)

Comment: @AndrewBarber...i didn't meant so....i am really very sorry if it hurted anybody and will keep your point in mind for future...

Comment: There is no problem with anyone's intelligence:) and he did not meant something like that I think. But anyway, thank you both again.